# Javascript Weird - I'm clueless

Tags: javascript, variables, for-loop, overriding

I'm working on this menu-system that's very similar to how operating systems do them.
Using jquery etc.

I have 2 comments down in the For Loop. It's basically outputting the last index each in the $(document).on('click')... function. But outside the document.on it works fine.

It's probably just an obvious problem but I've spent about an hour on this.. Thanks in advance!

```
    menu: function(title) {
        this.title = title;
        this.slug = slugify(title);
        this.icon = false;
        this.buttons = Object();
        this.num_buttons = 0;
        this.visible = false;
        this.timeout_id = null;
        this.is_hovering_dropdown = false;
        this.is_hovering_menu = false;


        this.render = function() {
            var that = this;
            var slug = that.slug;
            var str = '<li id="menu-' +slug +'"><a href="#" id="menu-toggle-' +slug + '">' + this.title + '</a>';

            if (this.num_buttons > 0) {
                str += '<ul id="menu-dropdown-' + slug + '" style="display: none;" class="dropdown">';
                for (var button in this.buttons) {

                    str += '<li><a href="#" id="menu-dropdown-' + slug + '-' +that.buttons[button]['slug'] +'">' +that.buttons[button]['title'] +'</a></li>'

                    alert(button) //new project, open project, save as etc.
                    $(document).on("click", "#menu-dropdown-" +slug + '-' + that.buttons[button]['slug'], function() {
                        $("#menu-dropdown-" + slug).hide("fade", 200);
                        that.visible = false;

                        alert(button);//save as, save as, save as, save as etc.
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: do you have a snipet of your html?

Comment: Are you waiting for the DOM to load before calling menu.render?

Comment: ew html concat in javascript. You should use a templating engine like JsRender and preserve your sanity!

Comment: also, are you getting any errors referencing "that" from within the function passed to `(document).on(...)`? Sometimes I have to do things like `($(document).on('click', '#...slug...', function(that) { ... func ...}).call(that);`

Comment: I took the advice Norgaurd gave and it doesn't work yet. I'm getting "String is not a function" at "(function () {...".

Comment: I give up on this. I'll just manually add all the events to each single button.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

Thanks to the order of operations, and scoping, all of your buttons are being saved with a reference to the *LAST* value of `button`.

What you want to do is put that assignment inside of an immediately-invoking function, and pass the button into that particular function-scope.

(function (button) { $(document). //......  }(button));

Everything inside of the immediate function should still have access to the static stuff outside of the immediate-function's scope (ie: `that`), **AND** it will also have a reference to the ***current*** value of `button`, as it's being invoked then and there.

The longer version of the story is that your buttons, when being created are being given a *reference* to `button`, rather than the ***value*** of `button`, therefore, when they're actually invoked at a later time, they reference the value of button as it currently exists (ie: the last value it was assigned in the loop).

Comment: That's kinda what I thought but I had no idea how to sort it out. Self-invoking function eh. Thank a lot :)

Comment: No worries.  Two things to note:  1) immediately-invoked (/self-invoked) functions are perfect for creating private properties: `var public_obj = (function () { var private_var = 23, private_func = function (num) { return private_var + num; }, public_method = function (num) { return private_func(num); }, public_api = { add_num : public_method };  return public_api; }());`  All of the private stuff is tamper-proof.  Even if the interface is crushed, its internals aren't compromised.   2) if it's an assignment, you can just `=func(){}()` if there's no assignment, wrap it `(func(){}())`